Acidity of Hydrogen in Aldehydes
Is hydrogen attatched to carbonyl group (like the hydrogen in methanal) in aldehydes just as acidic as an alpha hydrogen in aldehydes and ketones? If not, why?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71708/why-is-the-hydrogen-atom-adjacent-to-the-carbonyl-carbon-of-aldehyde-not-acidic

We can go beyond Waylander's answer. The hydrogen attached to a carbonyl group not only lacks strong protic character, is has some hydridic character (meaning it's more like $\ce{BH3}$ or $\ce{BH4^-}$ than $\ce{NH3}$ or $\ce{NH4^+}$). This may seem strange given the reputation of the carbonyl group as electronegative, but there is a molecular-orbital-based reason.
Acyl hydrides (sort of)
In an aldehyde, the nonbonding pairs on the oxygen atom are in the same plane as the bond between the carbonyl carbon and the aldehyde-function hydrogen. The electrons on the oxygen thereby overlap the otherwise vacant $\ce{C – H}$ antibonding orbital, weakening that bond but in exchange introducing an additional pi interaction within the carbonyl group. This process effectively displaces the $\ce{C – H}$ bonding pair towards hyfrogen, thus creating that hydridic contribution:

Aa written, the hydridic contribution is only very minor because a charge separation is required and the hydrogen is not very electronegative. But if a base, represented here as $\ce{B^-}$ (in applications it's usually an anionic base, especially hydroxide in water) is added, then the charge balance becomes more favorable and the hydrogen takes on greater hydridic character:

This enables hydride-transfer reactions such as the Cannizzaro reaction, in which the hydridic character of the hydrogen being discussed here is plainly evident.

Interesting approach, but protons by carbonyl aren't completely non-acidic

I made some modifications, but never heard of proton transfer off a carbonyl group. Bases typically end up adding to the carbonyl group.

Well, there's https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/64426/9961, but it's via reduction... so I guess it would indeed be hard to find an example, but could be possible.

No, it is not.
The acidity of alpha hydrogens in carbonyl compounds results from enolisation of the carbonyl allowing -ve charge to be stabilised by the carbonyl oxygen. This cannot occur on the aldehydic proton.
